# What's the point of Swift's function notation?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, language-features, swift-language

Why does Swift use this function notation:

```
func greet(person: String, day: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(person), today is \(day)."
}
```

Like, I don't get why it uses the small arrow `->` notation to specify return type. `func identifier() -> Type` instead of something more sensible, like `Type identifier()`.

I have seen similar notation in Haskell, but in Haskell it makes sense to me because Haskell uses curried functions, so the arrow represents function currying. In swift it just seems verbose and superfluous.

What was the reasoning behind this design choice?

Comment: What would you use instead? And why do you think `->` is related to currying? It's simply the [function type constructor](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#-.3E) in Haskell and it seems to play a similar role in Swift. If I had to guess, they are following (some of) the conventions of (some) functional languages.

Comment: (BTW, this question seems hard to answer unless we find a design document for Swift and/or one of its designers decides to answer :) )

Comment: Also, please [do not cross-post to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154622/reasoning-behind-swifts-function-notation).

Comment: "something more sensible, like `Type identifier()`" - more sensible if you only experience C syntax

Comment: Assume Swift used the "sensible" `Type identifier()` notation. How would you write `let closure: () -> Type`? `let closure: Type()?`

Comment: Oh wow, I just answered this question, not realizing I answered the cross post on SO.

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr: Mathematical notation.

In Mathematics, a function is map that takes things from one "Space" (a set) to another (another set). i.e. `f` could be a function taking elements from the natural numbers to the letters in the alphabet. The type of this would be `f:Real numbers -> Letters`
another example might be `g(x) = x + 1`. the type of this function might be `g:R -> R`. (where R are the real numbers.)

But theres a reason mathematicians write it like this: its intuitive. The arrows indicate how values are changing. You're going from elements in a first set to elements in a second. so for your example, you might say in your head: `greet` is a function that takes the tuple of two `Strings` to another `String`.

now, why should types come after the variable names? My guess is its for the same reason:

In mathematical proofs you often say things like "let m be any integer" which looks oddly like `let m:Int`.

That tends to sound better and more formal than the alternate "An Integer m has some value" : `int m;`

Comment: You are wrong. In maths, mapping notation is for specifying the image of an input under the mapping, not its "type." `f : x —> x + 1`

Comment: No, I'm not wrong. You're right too though. You can use the notation for both. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Notation

Comment: I don't see where on that page it says that it is used for "type." I see it says that for a function `f` with domain `X` and codomain `Y` then `f : X —> Y`, where each element of `Y` is an image of an element of `X` under the function `f`, but it says nowhere anything about "types".

Comment: Domain (`X`) and Codomain(`Y`), correct.  X and Y are Mathematical sets. I've not a category theorist or type theorist, but the distinction between Types and Sets is negligible for this audience.

Comment: Also, since we're being pedantic, "each element of Y is an image of an element of X under the function `f`" is the definition of Range, not Codomain. 
Ex: the codomain `Y` may contain an element `y` for which there is no element `x` within `X` such that `f(x) = y`

Comment: @theonlygusti What is a type in the sense you mean?

Comment: @JoeDaniels Types can easily be encoded as Sets, so there is no need for a distinction

Answer (score 3):

> Like, I don't get why it uses the small arrow -> notation to specify return type. func identifier() -> Type instead of something more sensible, like Type identifier().

This comment suggests to me that this question is really just meant to bash Swift for not being C/C++/Java. It's quite likely that nothing anyone could answer you will satisfy you.

In Swift, unlike C, C++ and Java, it's very common place (and indeed, actually possible) to return functions (closures) from functions.

Consider this example:

```
func incrementerMaker(startAt start: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var count = start
    return { count += 1; return count }
}

let incrementer = incrementerMaker(startAt: 0)

print(incrementer()) // 1
print(incrementer()) // 2
print(incrementer()) // 3
```

For one, take note that this is a curried function. It's not as common in Swift as in Haskell, but it's certainly a possibility.

All instance methods are curried functions. This is pretty handy, because it means you can pass them around without yet binding them to act on a specific instance. Consider the function `String.uppercased()`:

```
print(type(of: String.uppercased)) //prints: (String) -> () -> String
```

The type `(String) -> () -> String` makes it very clear what series of steps the function must undergo until it produces its final result. Firstly, it expects to be invoked with a single `String` argument. This binds the `self` instance, and returns an instance method of type `() -> String`. This tells you it expects to be invoked with no arguments, producing a `String` result.

How would that type signature for that function look like, given your "sensible" `Type identifier()` syntax? The function being returned is anonymous, so there's no identifier, and unlike C or C++, it's not a function pointer, so there's no `*` symbol to be used, either.

Comment: Interesting.  I haven't yet done any work with swift, but that *is* a very nice syntax for returning a closure.  *And* a nice way of handling the distinction between bound and unbound instance methods.